# Sql statement return with zero result

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to choose the row where

1)`list.ispublic = 1`
2)`userlist.userid='aaa'` AND `userlist.listid=list.listid`

I need 1)+2)

There is a row already but this statement can not get that row, is there any problem?

List  table:

```
ListID  ListName    Creator IsRemindSub IsRemindUnSub   IsPublic    CreateDate  LastModified    Reminder
1       test2       aaa     0           0               1           2012-03-09  NULL            NULL
```

user_list table (No row):

```
UserID ListID UserRights
```

My test version

```
SELECT * 
FROM list l 
INNER JOIN user_list ul ON ul.ListID = l.ListID 
WHERE l.IsPublic = 1 AND ul.UserID = '09185346d'
```

This is the  Result when there are two list in user_list has aaa , and one list is public in list, so will this cause double retrieve of that one public list in list if i get it in php ?

```
ListID    ListName    Creator    IsRemindSub    IsRemindUnSub    IsPublic    CreateDate    LastModified    Reminder    UserID    ListID    UserRights
1         test2       aaa        0              0                1           2012-03-09    NULL                        aaa       1         read
2         t2          aaa        0              0                1           2012-03-09    NULL                        aaa       2         read
```

Comment: Implicit (Oracle style) joins are "inner" joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to only `SELECT` the fields you actually need.  Second, write your `JOINS` explicitly - it helps readability.  For example:

```
SELECT l.*, ul.*
FROM list l
INNER JOIN user_list ul ON ul.ListID = l.ListID
WHERE l.IsPublic = 1
  AND ul.UserID = 'aaa'
```

Incidentally, if you have no data in your `user_list` table, then you have no way to meet the requirements you have set.  If as you put it "userlist.listid=list.listid" is necessary and the `user_list` table is empty, you will always get zero rows returned.

***Edit:*** And no, it won't cause rows to be retrieved double.  Whatever results you get with your SQL query will be the same results you get in a PHP script - the mechanism for retrieving the data is the same.

Comment: @user782104: I updated my answer.  If you're adding any more data to your initial question, please don't copy/paste tabs into the question as it doesn't display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If your user_list table contains no rows, that query will return no results.

You want a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT list.col_1, list.col_2 -- etc...
FROM list
LEFT JOIN user_list ON user_list.ListID = List.ListID
WHERE list.IsPublic = 1  
   OR user_list.UserID = 'aaa'
```

Comment: He wants an `INNER JOIN` according to his specs above: "userlist.userid='aaa' AND userlist.listid=list.listid".  The fact that the list ID's have to match would indicate an inner join.

Comment: I think the question is flawed. :)